# post custom form request

Tags: forms

I need to insert a form into one tab contained into product page.
you can see an example in [this page](http://magento.article-marketing-design.com/fauteuil-releveur-electrique-helsinki-avec-inclinaison-combinee-en-tissu-traite-teflon-bleu-ciel.html)

I created a static block that contain the form, the action is a cms page.

so, I need to insert a php function that send me the data insert into the form.

How can I do this action?

Answer (score 1):

Set your action of form as

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('module/controller/method'); ?>" >
```

Then create a controller with the corresponding method.

```
function Name(){
if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {

    $model = Mage::getModel('module/model_name');
    $model->setData($data);
    try {
        $model->save();
    }catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->_forward('NoRoute');
    }
}
```

To send email do following

```
$translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');

            /* @var $translate Mage_Core_Model_Translate */

            $translate->setTranslateInline(false);

            try {               

                $postObject = new Varien_Object();

                $postObject->setData($data);

                $mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');

                /* @var $mailTemplate Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template */

                $mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))                 
                    ->sendTransactional(
                        'test_email_template',
                        'general',
                        'receiver_email_id', null, array('data' => $postObject)
                    );

                $translate->setTranslateInline(true);

            } catch (Exception $e) {

                $translate->setTranslateInline(true);

            }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I need to insert the php function `mail` and can you explain well your solution please? I'm a magento newbie :(

Comment: You can use zend mail function for your magento form.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
try{
    $mail = new Zend_Mail();
    $mail->setFrom("fromemail","fromname");
    $mail->addTo("toemail","toname");
    $mail->setSubject("subject");
    $mail->setBodyHtml(" body text"); 
    $mail->send();
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMassage(); 
}
```

Hope,It may work for you..